# How to return list to json

Tags: getjson

Hi I have a list of data which i want to return to json along with some hard coded string values.
    List list= new List();
    list= Customer.GetVisitinfo(customerId);
The code i am using for hard coded string values is :
    String str = string.Format(
                    "[ {{\"Id\": \"{0}\", \"Name\": \"enter code here{1}\"}}],
                     customer.Id,
                    customer.FirstName + " " + customer.LastName);

Answer (score 0):

This code is Python specific

```
from django.utils import simplejson
var = simplejson.dumps(list)
```

Basically, **dumps** does the trick, look for it in your particular language.